# Intermittent Access Violation when using C# to access C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm linking from c# to a quite complex c++ dll. I need to create a lot of dllexport funtions so I can use the dll in c#. To get started, I added a .cpp file and created a simple test function:

c++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int32_t Test(){
    return 10;
}
```

c#:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Test());
}

[DllImport("Test.dll", EntryPoint = "Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern Int32 Test();
```

This test works perfectly 90% of the time and then suddenly....

```
The program '[4712] Test.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

Everything seems fine, no idea what causes it or even how to begin to track down the problem. It's weird that it is so intermittent. I'm not a c++ programmer really so I've no idea what might cause this behaviour, or even how to debug and find the problem.

Hope some kind soul can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
SetLastError = true
```

is useless unless you are using Windows API.

And set the

```
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl
```

like

```
[DllImport("Test.dll", EntryPoint = "Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true)]
```

---

Note that there is code other than your method that could be executed. A DLL can (and often does) have a [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. Often in this method "global" variables of the dll are initialized, and so are methods that must be called a single time. This method is normally called at least twice: `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` when the dll is loaded and `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` when the process ends/the dll is unloaded.

Comment: Thanks for that, but there is still a very intermittent access violation. I'll update the question with your code.

Comment: @GordonTruslove Then perhaps you aren't running exactly that code, or you forgot to tell us something important... Are you using Visual Studio? What version of C#? x86 or x64?

Comment: I copied and pasted it. Just ran the program 7 times in a row and it worked. The 8th time it failed. Could it be something in the rest of the dll, there is a lot of other code, but I'm not calling it in the test?

Comment: @GordonTruslove A dll has code that is autoexecuted at the start. It is normally called [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @GordonTruslove Instead of just running the code, debug it.  That access violation will show up in the debugger, and then inspect the call stack to see what is causing it.

Comment: @GordonTruslove If you want to debug, remember to enable the option `Enable native code debugging` (properties of the C# project, Debug)

Comment: The DllMain suggestion seems to be the solution. I found that function and  there is other code running which I commented out. Now the test works every time. So at least I know where to start debugging. Any chance you could put that as a separate answer and I'll mark you correct.

Comment: "Enable native code", brilliant, never heard of that before. I'll check that out.

Comment: @GordonTruslove Added something about DllMain

Comment: Of course, with the debugging turned on, it now never fails. Oh well, at least I have a starting point. Thanks guys, I had no clue what to do before.

Comment: @GordonTruslove `DllMain` is a special function in that there are things you should not do within that function.  The list of things are described in the reference to it in MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Having said this, since your DLL has an explicit `DllMain`, then it must have needed to do something at DLL initialization time.  Otherwise, there would no need to write a `DllMain`, so something in the initialization is probably causing the issue.