# How to call cygwin compiled C++ from .NET Core?

Tags: c#, c++, cmake, .net-core, cygwin

I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121129/intermittent-access-violation-when-using-c-sharp-to-access-c-dll):

I am working on Windows but my intention is to make my code work on Linux too later on (therefore I work with cygwin and clion for C++ ). VS2017 to compile the C# for a .NET Core app with a normal C# compiler.  My problem is getting this error in visual studio:

> "The program '[19944] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -1073741819
>   (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'."

Here is my cmake file (generated with clion):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10) project(callFromCsharp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(callFromCsharp SHARED library.cpp)
```

Here is my C++ code in library.cpp:

```
#include <cstdint>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int32_t Test(){
    return 10;
}
```

This is my cmake call generated by clion

> C:\Users\Daant.CLion2018.1\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/Daant/CLionProjects/callFromCsharp/cmake-build-release
>   --target callFromCsharp -- -j 6

Here is my C# code:

```
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("cygcallFromCsharp.dll", EntryPoint = "Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern Int32 Test();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var res = Test();
            Console.WriteLine($"Done! {res}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

How to solve this? I just want to call a C++ method without errors or exceptions.

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. As you are writing C# to run cygwin  program ?

Comment: Cygwin i use to compile the c++ code. C# is to write the .net core app and compiled with a normal c# compiler.

Comment: If you are trying to call a cygwin dll directly  from c# code, it will not work as cywin dll inizialization is different from standard windows code

Comment: Yes, I learned that the hard way. How should I do it differently as a cygwin user?

Comment: Or all cygwin code (and no C#) or all windows code.

Comment: You chose cygwin for xplat support, however, clang is another way to do that without involving virtualization (i.e. without involving cygwin). clang has a native Windows executable and produces native Windows executables. It can do the same on Linux.

Answer (score 5):

**Lets begin with what not to do**

when loading Cygwin dll from C# (I guess from Visual studio it will be the same).

1. do not use AnyCPU as platform, prefer to use x64 or x86 platform, in respectively to the Cygwin dll.
2. for some reason, I didn't figured out yet why, calling `sprintf`, `sscanf` ,`stringstream` ... and prints to console methods from the dll cause the program to halt.

**Now What you can do:**

1. Make sure cygwin bin folder added to path, or copy your DLL's dependencies to the DLL's folder (dependencies are usually: Cygwin1.dll, cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll cygstdc++-6.dll. use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool to check).
2. Just to make sure: add EXPORT_API macro, use it on each exported method. like:

`#define EXPORT_API extern "C" __cdecl __declspec(dllexport)`

3. Your DLL sample is very simple, compile your code using Cygwin console:
   `g++ -c library.cpp; g++ -o cygcallFromCsharp.dll library.o`
4. I used from C# the following (debug running dir set to dll location):

`DllImport(@"cygcallFromCsharp.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 static extern int Test();`

Hope it will help.

Comment: I am afraid it does not but EXPORT_API was a good hint to make it cross platform (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-porting/index.html if defined). The problems you mentioned about x64 and PATH, I learned the hard way before, Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a dotnet loader which is compatible with cygwin.
You can find it here: https://github.com/smx-smx/EzDotnet

In order to be able to use Cygwin from .NET (without any crashes) the entry point **MUST** be a Cygwin application, compiled and linked under cygwin.

I added a cygwin sample that demonstrates the use of P/Invoke as well as `read(2)` and `write(2)` to redirect the C# stdin/stdout to cygwin (otherwise it wouldn't be visible)

> ./samples/cli/ezdotnet.exe ./CoreCLR/cygcoreclrhost.dll ./samples/Managed/Cygwin/bin/Debug/net5.0/Cygwin.dll ManagedSample.EntryPoint Entry